# Can't write file to Android 2.3 device in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I just found window.requestFileSystem could not execute and report error code 9 when I run the PhoneGap based Android app in a real Android 2.3 device.

But it executes successfully in a virtual Android 4.2 device.

Any one can help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do the following:

- Check your permissions on your application - They're most likely correct if the app works on Android 4.2's emulator
- Make sure that your SD Card is installed and isn't auto-mounted by the phone's software.  Depending on the device, when you plug your device into your computer, it may try to automount the SDCard making it unreadable to the phone.

There was a similar post on the Google Group here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/J6UXAwmj040